# Helm chart template `range` operator executes even when the list is empty

Tags: kubernetes-helm

The below block runs at-least once even when the list specified in the `values.yaml` is empty.

```yaml
containers:
      - name: create-directory
        image: "{{ .Values.container.image }}"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - |
            {{- range .Values.directories }}
            dir_path="/var/log/at/{{ . }}"
            echo $dir_path

            # Check if the directory exists
            if [ -d "$dir_path" ]; then
              echo "Directory $dir_path already exists."
            else
              # Create the directory
              mkdir -p "$dir_path" && echo "Directory $dir_path created."
            fi
            {{- end }}
```

This is unexpected as the loop with `range` should not be executed.

I have even tried using a `if/else` block and capturing the length of the `Values.directories` list length and making sure only when it is greater than zero the range block should execute. This seems to be not working either.

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What exactly do you have set as `directories:` in `values.yaml` (or, if relevant, additional `helm -f` values files or `helm --set` options)?  Specifying container-internal filesystem paths as part of deploy-time configuration seems a little unusual, can you put this setup somewhere else in your application (in a Dockerfile `RUN` instruction; in an entrypoint wrapper script)?

Comment: @DavidMaze The `values.yaml` file holds the `directories: []` and this value is overwritten from a terraform helm release resource block.

I want to update the file system on each node, I use the `hostPath` to mount it and then create directories inside the mounted directory using this daemonset conatiner.